# Play a System Sound using HTML

Tags: html

I would like to know if is possible to play a SYSTEM sound using HTML 5 (even with js).

I recently found out [this article](http://css-tricks.com/8954-play-sound-on-hover/) that show how to do it, but for my understanding is only with attached external sound (like mp3 or other). I would need instead use some OS SYSTEM sound.

Thanks guys for helping to understand css better :)

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/aural.html if you haven't seen this yet. Afaik this stuff works only on opera.

Comment: aural is interesting for screen reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this to be possible without something like maybe an ActiveX control, and even then, support would be extremely spotty. If this were possible, it could cause a huge security vulnerability. Why don't you just get a .mp3 of the OS SYSTEM sound that you want to play and use the same trick that you linked to?

Comment: I understand I did not think about security issue. Your is a good point. Thanks for your answer.